# What "FreeBSD for Linux Geeks" Guides Exist?

Tags: linux, freebsd

I have been using linux for quite some time now, usually Ubuntu these days, but have used Debian and Gentoo too, and have been meaning to get started with [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org) for a long time.

While both are very similar at the user level (I used FreeBSD systems in college, and never noticed much of a change once I installed linux at home), are there any good guides that give the main differences in terms of setting up FreeBSD systems if you are familiar with linux. I have also heard very good things about FreeBSD, especially from the college sysadmins, and the fact that you can run ZFS with FreeBSD relatively straightforwardly has given me the impetus to try it out.

I am sure there are a number of gotchas involved though, so was wondering what guides / sites exist for this - assuming they exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly dated, but the following articles go over a few of the differences including startup scripts, kernel, software installation, etc.:

[Comparing GNU/Linux and FreeBSD](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/comparing_linux_and_freebsd)

[FreeBSD for Linux Users](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/bsd/2004/11/11/FreeBSD_Basics.html)

Answer (score 3):

[The BSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/) and [UNIX and BSD Books](http://www.openbsd.org/books.html) come to mind.

Comment: +1 for the handbook -- Good for anyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind buying a book I found [Absolute FreeBSD 2nd edition](http://nostarch.com/abs_bsd2.htm) to be a very good guide to FreeBSD.  Covering both running it on both the laptop/desktop and server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for guides to getting you started, besides the FreeBSD handbook which is amazing there is [BSDguides.org](http://www.bsdguides.org/), while slightly dated in terms of material and the website itself it is still very good and contains a lot of information for people looking for particular solutions to problems.